# Seems to be a problem with multiplication and allocating the new values the multVact

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, vertices

Two vectors are created and values are assigned to both the vectors and then the two vectors are multiplied with each other. (A matrix multiplication). Gives a segmentation fault error in the multiply function. Is it something to with trying to access an location out of the scope?

```
#include<iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int n;
vector <int> mat1Rows;
vector <int> mat2Rows;
vector <int> multRows;
vector <vector<int> > mat1;
vector <vector<int> > mat2;
vector <vector<int> > multMat;

void assignValues(int num){

        for(int i = 0; i < num; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < num; j++){
                        mat1Rows.push_back(j);
                        mat2Rows.push_back(j);
                }
                mat1.push_back(mat1Rows);
                mat2.push_back(mat2Rows);

        mat1Rows.clear();
        mat2Rows.clear();
        }
}

void multiply(int n){

        for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
                for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j){
                        for(int k = 0; k < n; ++k){

                multMat[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
                        }
                }
    }
}

void displayMult(int n){

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){

            cout << multMat[i][j] << " " ;
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

}

int main(){

    cout << "Enter the size of the matrix: ";
    cin >> n;

    assignValues(n);

    multiply(n);

    displayMult(n);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Your program does not compile. Please, add required includes.

Comment: "Is it something to with trying to access an location out of the scope?" - this is pretty much what segmentation fault means. The easiest way to find it is to step through your program line by line with debugger.

Comment: @NO_NAME Added the includes.

Comment: `multMat` vector is empty at the moment when you try to get a reference to its element with `multMat[i][j]`.

Comment: @Rashmika97 Use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` to access the items in the vector.  You will then see that the program will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception instead of just a seg fault when it encounters an `at()` call that is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
 multMat[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];
```

There is no memory inside `multMat` as you didn't reserve any memory for the elements. You need to tell vector to allocate memory. You can do that with [resize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize), to allocate the memory for the elements and change the size of the vector..

```
 void multiply(int n) {
       multMat.resize(n);
       for (auto&& i : multMat) {
             i.resize(n);
       }
       ... rest of the code ...
  }
```

The [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does not perform bounds checking. So if you specify an index outside of allowed bounds and try to assign something to returned reference, undefined behavior happens. Use [`std::vector::at()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) to be always sure your indices are valid.

Comment: Btw, `reserve()` does not change the size of the vector.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `resize()` instead of `reserve()`? `reserve()` would prevent the segmentation fault but accessing fields outside of `size()` of the vector still smells like an undefined behavior to me.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to reserve memory since this is a dynamic allocation?

Comment: The `operator[]` does not perform any allocation. It does not perform any checking. It is undefined behavior to use it outside of bounds.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that in the case of vector of some fundamental type it doesn't do much a difference. Better to know when to use `resize()` and when `reserve()`, though. It could cause some pretty weird error in vector of objects with constructor and destructor. Beside that, an attempt to use `push_back` would override the data if only `resize()` if only `resize()` was called.

Comment: `std::vector::get`? I cannot find it in the reference page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/